# Yml must be stored as a dictionary/hash

Tags: ansible

I have a yaml file of usernames and their ssh keys stored like this:

```yaml
---
- user: bob
  name: bob McBob
  ssh_keys:
   - ssh-rsa ...
- user: fred
  name: fred McFred
  ssh_keys:
   - ssh-rsa ...
```

I'm trying to grab the `user` and `ssh_keys` keys so i can use this file to setup the users on linux hosts

It seems Ansible does not like the format of this file though, as this simple task throws an error:

```yaml
- name: Get SSH Keys
  include_vars:
    file: ../admins.yml
    name: ssh_keys
```

```
TASK [network-utility-servers : Get SSH Keys] *******************************************************************************************************************************
task path: main.yml:1
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ssh_keys": {}
    },
    "ansible_included_var_files": [],
    "changed": false,
    "message": "admins.yml must be stored as a dictionary/hash"
}
```

Unfortunately I can't change the format of the `admins.yml` file as it is used in other tools and changing the format will break them.
Any suggestions on how I can work around this?

Looks like ansible wants the `admins.yml` file to look like this:

```yaml
---
foo:
 - user: bob
   name bob mcbob
   ssh_keys:
     - ssh-rsa ..
```

Answer (score 4):

As you found out, `include_vars` is expecting a file containing dict key(s) at the top level. But there are other ways to read yaml files in ansible.

If you cannot change the file, the simplest way is to read its content inside a variable using a [`file` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_lookup.html) and the [`from_yaml` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json).

Here is an example playbook. For this test, your above example data was stored in `admins.yml` in the same folder as the playbook. Adapt accordingly.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    admins: "{{  lookup('file', 'admins.yml') | from_yaml }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Show admin users list
      debug:
        var: admins
```

Which gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show admin users list] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "admins": [
        {
            "name": "bob McBob",
            "ssh_keys": [
                "ssh-rsa ..."
            ],
            "user": "bob"
        },
        {
            "name": "fred McFred",
            "ssh_keys": [
                "ssh-rsa ..."
            ],
            "user": "fred"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the given vars file has not a valid format. You could use a task to fix the file in the fashion you described, and then attempt to load it.

The `lineinfile` task could be of use to do the trick, as in below example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
 
  tasks:
  - name: fix vars file
    lineinfile:
      path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/vars_file.yml"
      insertafter: "^---$"
      line: "ssh_keys:"
      backup: yes

  - name: Get SSH Keys
    include_vars:
      file: "{{ playbook_dir }}/vars_file.yml"

  - debug: var=ssh_keys
```

If you are not supposed to edit that file, you could copy to a new file name (vars_file_fixed.yml), then apply the lineinfile and load it.

cheers